# Десериализация XML-файла в native C++

Tags: c++, xml, сериализация

Как выполнить десериализацию XML-файла, созданного в C#, в native C++?
Говоря точнее, существует файл XML, созданный в C# и представляющий сериализацию объектов C#.
Требуется прочитать его посредством native C++ так, чтобы десериализовать записанные в нём объекты.
Стандартная библиотека C++ этой возможности не поддерживает.
- Какие внешние библиотеки поддерживают эту возможность?
- На первый взгляд, BOOST. Есть ли у кого-нибудь опыт использования BOOST`а для этой цели?

Comment: В принципе не важно наверное где был создан XML. А прочитать можно в большинстве случаев например с помощью tinyxml.

Comment: Можно использовать генератор парсеров, который по схеме XML выдаст набор классов C++ и код парсера. [Здесь](https://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) список подобных утилит, некоторые для C++.

Comment: Достаточно общий вопрос. Если вы хотели узнать, есть ли специализированные средства в стандартной библиотеке C++, то ответ нет, но, как уже писали выше, существуют решения в виде внешних библиотек.

Comment: Допустим, вы как-то десериализовали C# объекты в C++, как вы представляете дальнейшую работу с ними? Надеюсь вы не ожидаете от них поведения как если бы это был C#?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Хороший вопрос. Как я понял пстановщика, это простые структуры данных. Но я уточню, спасибо!

Comment: @VladimirGamalian C#, выполняя XML-сериализaцию объекта, записывает лишь его properties. Так что изначально никакого поведения от них не ожидается. Просто склад данных.

Comment: Так если там просто данные, можно использовать любой XML-парсер общего назначения. В чём проблема?